# State variable hook does not increment within closure

Tags: reactjs

[codesandbox.io/s/github/Tmcerlean/battleship](http://codesandbox.io/s/github/Tmcerlean/battleship)

I am developing a simple board game and need to increment a state variable when a player clicks on a cell with a valid move.

The functionality for validating the move and making the move is all in place, however, I am having difficulty updating the state within the event listener.

I can see that the state is being updated when observed from a `useEffect` hook, but not when viewed from within the function (even following successive calls).

I have done some reading and believe it could have something to do with having a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/), but I am not certain.

---

My approach to solve this issue was to remove and then re-add the click event listener following every click by the user.

My assumption was that this would cause the correct (newly incremented) state variable to be picked up. Unfortunately, this does not appear to be the case and within the event listener function, the variable is never incremented from 0.

---

I initialise the state variable here:

```
const [placedShips, setPlacedShips] = useState(0);
```

Next, a click event listener is applied to each cell within the gameboard:

```
const clickListener = (e) => {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  let direction = currentShip().direction;
  let start = parseInt(e.target.id);
  let end = start + currentShip().length - 1;
  if (playerGameboard.checkValidCoordinates(direction, start, end)) {
    playerGameboard.placeShip(placedShips, direction, start, end);
    setPlacedShips((oldValue) => oldValue + 1);
    console.log(placedShips);
  }
};

const setEventListeners = () => {
  const gameboardArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));
  gameboardArray.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      clickListener(e);
    });
  });
};
```

You will see that the `setPlacedships` state variable is incremented here and there is a console log to report its value.

I am aware that the `useState` hook is asynchronous and so `console.log` will show 0 for the first time it is called. Consequently, I have a `useEffect` hook deployed outside of the function which also contains a `console.log` to report the changed value of `setPlacedShips`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  removeEventListeners();
  setEventListeners();
  console.log(placedShips)
}, [placedShips])
```

After every click the `placedShips` variable is incremented by 1 and then two functions are run:

```
const removeEventListeners = () => {
  const gameboardArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));
  gameboardArray.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.removeEventListener("click", (e) => {
      clickListener(e);
    });
  });
};
```

which is immediately followed by the original `setEventListeners` function:

```
const setEventListeners = () => {
  const gameboardArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));
  gameboardArray.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      clickListener(e);
    });
  });
};
```

As mentioned above, the issue is that the console log within the `setEventListeners` function constantly remains at 0, while the console log within the `useEffect` hook increments as expected.

For reference, here is the full component I am working on currently:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import gameboardFactory from "../../factories/gameboardFactory";
import Table from "../Reusable/Table";
import "./GameboardSetup.css";

// -----------------------------------------------
//
// Desc: Gameboard setup phase of game
//
// -----------------------------------------------

let playerGameboard = gameboardFactory();

const GameboardSetup = () => {
  const [humanSetupGrid, setHumanSetupGrid] = useState([]);
  const [ships, _setShips] = useState([
    {
      name: "carrier",
      length: 5,
      direction: "horizontal",
    },
    {
      name: "battleship",
      length: 4,
      direction: "horizontal",
    },
    {
      name: "cruiser",
      length: 3,
      direction: "horizontal",
    },
    {
      name: "submarine",
      length: 3,
      direction: "horizontal",
    },
    {
      name: "destroyer",
      length: 2,
      direction: "horizontal",
    },
  ]);
  const [placedShips, setPlacedShips] = useState(0);

  const createGrid = () => {
    const cells = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      cells.push(0);
    }
  };

  const createUiGrid = () => {
    const cells = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      cells.push(i);
    }
    let counter = -1;
    const result = cells.map((cell) => {
      counter++;
      return <div className="cell" id={counter} />;
    });
    setHumanSetupGrid(result);
  };

  const setUpPlayerGrid = () => {
    // createGrid('grid');
    createUiGrid();
  };

  const currentShip = () => {
    return ships[placedShips];
  };

  const clickListener = (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    let direction = currentShip().direction;
    let start = parseInt(e.target.id);
    let end = start + currentShip().length - 1;
    if (playerGameboard.checkValidCoordinates(direction, start, end)) {
      playerGameboard.placeShip(placedShips, direction, start, end);
      setPlacedShips((oldValue) => oldValue + 1);
      console.log(placedShips);
    }
  };

  const setEventListeners = () => {
    const gameboardArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));
    gameboardArray.forEach((cell) => {
      cell.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        clickListener(e);
      });
      cell.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        let direction = currentShip().direction;
        let start = parseInt(cell.id);
        let end = start + currentShip().length - 1;
        if (currentShip().direction === "horizontal") {
          const newShip = [];
          if (playerGameboard.checkValidCoordinates(direction, start, end)) {
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
              newShip.push(i);
            }
            newShip.forEach((cell) => {
              gameboardArray[cell].classList.add("test");
            });
          }
        } else {
          const newShip = [];
          if (playerGameboard.checkValidCoordinates(direction, start, end)) {
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i += 10) {
              newShip.push(i);
            }
            newShip.forEach((cell) => {
              gameboardArray[cell].classList.add("test");
            });
          }
        }
      });
      cell.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        let direction = currentShip().direction;
        let start = parseInt(cell.id);
        let end = start + currentShip().length - 1;
        if (currentShip().direction === "horizontal") {
          const newShip = [];
          if (playerGameboard.checkValidCoordinates(direction, start, end)) {
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
              newShip.push(i);
            }
            newShip.forEach((cell) => {
              gameboardArray[cell].classList.remove("test");
            });
          }
        } else {
          const newShip = [];
          if (playerGameboard.checkValidCoordinates(direction, start, end)) {
            for (let i = start; i <= end; i += 10) {
              newShip.push(i);
            }
            newShip.forEach((cell) => {
              gameboardArray[cell].classList.remove("test");
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  };

  const removeEventListeners = () => {
    const gameboardArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));
    gameboardArray.forEach((cell) => {
      cell.removeEventListener("click", (e) => {
        clickListener(e);
      });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setUpPlayerGrid();
    // setUpComputerGrid();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(humanSetupGrid);
  }, [humanSetupGrid]);

  // Re-render the component to enable event listeners to be added to generated grid
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setEventListeners();
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    removeEventListeners();
    setEventListeners();
    console.log(placedShips);
  }, [placedShips]);

  return (
    <div className="setup-container">
      <div className="setup-information">
        <p className="setup-information__p">Add your ships!</p>
        <button
          className="setup-information__btn"
          onClick={() => console.log(placedShips)}
        >
          Rotate
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="setup-grid">
        <Table grid={humanSetupGrid} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GameboardSetup;
```

I am quite confused what is happening here and have been stuck on this problem for a couple of days now - if anybody has any suggestions then they would be highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you passing a function to `setPlacedShips`? Shouldn't this just be `setPlacedShips(placedShips + 1)`?

Comment: I tried this before and actually this prevented the state from incrementing altogether. Somebody recommended changing it to the way it is now and it functioned correctly (when viewed from the useEffect hook). I'm not sure if this is correct, but appears to partially function at least.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion  and amendments @JanezKuhar - I have updated the post now.

Comment: Could be related to the fact that you are "playing" with the DOM. Since React has his own way to manipulate the DOM, using `document.querySelectorAll(".cell")` to remove/add listener, could create the issue you are seeing. In React you should not manipulate the DOM in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the input @GiovanniEsposito - I figured it is likely something like this, any idea how else it could be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> const removeEventListeners = () => {
>   const gameboardArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cell"));
>   gameboardArray.forEach((cell) => {
>     cell.removeEventListener("click", (e) => {
>       clickListener(e);
>     });
>   });
> };
> ```

The above code does not remove any event listeners, which is probably the reason why `0` is still being logged. You pass a new anonymous function to `removeEventListener`. Since the function is just created it will never remove any event listeners, because it is not registered as an event listener.

Two different functions that do the same are not equal, which is why the event listener is not removed.

```
const a = (e) => clickListener(e); // passed to addEventListener
const b = (e) => clickListener(e); // passed to removeEventListener
console.log(a == b); //=> false
```

To add and remove events you cannot use anonymous functions. You either have to use named functions, or store the function in a variable. Then register and remove the event listener using the function name or variable.

Since you only forward the `event` to the `clickListener` you can simply replace your event handler registration with:

```
cell.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
```

Then remove it using:

```
cell.removeEventListener("click", clickListener);
```

---

Note that this scenario could've been avoided if you passed your event handlers using a more React approach. Instead of using `cell.addEventHandler(...)` you could've passed the event on creation of this element. eg. `<div className='cell' id={counter} onClick={clickListener} />`

Comment: Hi @3limin4t0r - firstly, thank you for the detailed response. I have made the suggested changes to the event handler registrations, but unfortunately I am seeing the same issue persist regarding the variable not incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

When working with React you should try to not manipulate the DOM manually. React Components have Synthetic Events, which means that you don't need to add event listeners the vanilla way.

Just add each synthetic event to the cell component with its corresponding handler.

You can do it in the createUiGrid function:

```
const createUiGrid = () => {
    const cells = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      cells.push(i);
    }
    let counter = -1;
    const result = cells.map((cell) => {
      counter++;
      return <div className="cell" id={counter} onClick={onClickHandler} onMouseOut={onMouseOutHandler} onMouseOver={onMouseOverHandler} />;
    });
    setHumanSetupGrid(result);
  };
```

And then just move the code you did on vanilla to each corresponding handler (be sure to remove all listener manipulation before testing).